# How to make a single combobox sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a single combobox sortable. Jquery UI documentation about sortables mentions, that sortable should be setup like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable();
```

When I've put in the selector it made all my Select2 elements sortable:

```
$("ul.select2-selection__rendered").sortable()
```

I want to make it so only one element in specific div is sortable. I've tried copying CSS Selector path from my browser and got an error:

```
var outpatient = document.querySelectorAll('#department-outpatient > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(1)')[0];
outpatient.sortable({
  // ...
});
```

> TypeError: outpatient.sortable is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `outpatient` variable will hold an Element object as you use `querySelectorAll()` to retrieve it. `sortable()` relies on jQuery, and so needs to be called on a jQuery object. Therefore to fix this you can create a jQuery object from `outpatient` and then call `sortable()` on it:

```
var outpatient = document.querySelectorAll('#department-outpatient > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(1)')[0];
$(outpatient).sortable({
  // ...
});
```

Taking this a step further, use jQuery itself to select the element. Also note that I'm sure that you can simplify that selector. It seems far too specific.

```
var $outpatient = $('#department-outpatient > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(1)');
$outpatient.sortable({
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works as intended! You've cleared some things up for me :)